# How to a full-width text input in header in React Navigation 6?

Tags: css, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

In my React Native (Expo) application, I wanted to upgrade [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) from V5 to V6. However, I could not make `TextInput` in stack navigator header full-width. I tried `'auto'` and `'100%'` for the `width` value in styling, however neither helped with a real wide textbox.

Here is the link for Expo snack for reproduction: https://snack.expo.io/@vahdet/reactnavigation6-headerbar and the `App.js` content from it is below. I guess I am short of some [flexbox](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/6.x/upgrading-from-5.x/#header-now-uses-flexbox) knowledge in `headerSearchBarStyle`:

```js
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';
import { AppearanceProvider } from 'react-native-appearance';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

enableScreens();
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

const Search = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

  // Customize header
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerTitle: () => (
        <TextInput
          style={styles.headerSearchBarStyle}
          value={searchText}
          onChangeText={(val) => setSearchText(val)}
          containerStyle={styles.searchBarContainerStyle}
          placeholder="Search..."
          returnKeyType="search"
          textContentType="none"
          cancelButtonTitle="Cancel"
        />
      )
    })
  }, [navigation, searchText]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.view}>
      {!searchText ? (
        <Text>Search results go here</Text>
      ) : (
        <Text>Initial (no search) content goes here</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AppearanceProvider>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <HomeStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Search">
          <HomeStack.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
        </HomeStack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    </AppearanceProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerSearchBarStyle: {
    width: 'auto', // also tried '100%'
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
});

export default App;
```

> **EDIT**: After [Kartikey's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68432974/4636715) I want to elaborate that by *full-width*, I do not necessarily mean the full *screen* width: There may be scenarios with `headerLeft` (e.g. back button) or `headerRight` components at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Use Device Width

```
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";

const ScreenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

and

```
headerSearchBarStyle: {
    width: ScreenWidth,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    margin: 10,
  },
```

You can also set it to `width: ScreenWidth - 30`, just to give some margin

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/reactnavigation6-headerbar)

Comment: Looks great when it is the only header element. But, would it still work when child stack screens (i.e. with back button) and maybe with some other buttons to the right?